# How can I fix the header of the table with fpdf?

Tags: php, fpdf

This is my code,

```
$head = array('Dependencia', 'Endoso', 'Emp', 'Nombre', 'Edad', 'Fec I Vig', 'Certificado', 'Parentesco', 'Fecha Ant', 'Descuento', 'Tarifa', 'CI', 'CEE', 'CP 10%', 'Suma', 'Iva', 'Costo Vig', 'Total', '1era Quincena', 'CT', 'Retroactivo', '2da Quincena', 'CT', 'Total Mensual');
$w=array(30,15,12,40,12,18,18,18,18,18,15,10,10,15,15,15,15,15,15,10,20,15,10,20); // en este arreglo definiremos el ancho de cada columna 
        $current_y = $this->GetY();
        $current_x = $this->GetX();
        for($i=0;$i<count($head);$i++){
            $this->MultiCell($w[$i],6,$head[$i],1,'C',true);
            $this->SetXY($current_x + $w[$i], $current_y);
            $current_x = $this->GetX();
        }
        $this->Ln();
```

And I get that:

http://imageshack.com/a/img853/5349/uut5.jpg

How Can I fix it?

Comment: Increase the width for `1era Quincena` and `2da Quincena`? ie. change from `15` to `20`

Comment: Hi Sean, I need the wrap because if I change the width, the columns do not fit into PDF.

Comment: Change the cell height for your header loop. It's currently 6. Try 12 or more.

Comment: Increase the cell height from `$this->MultiCell($w[$i],6,$head[$i],1,'C',true);` to `$this->MultiCell($w[$i],12,$head[$i],1,'C',true)` or more